# Orientability of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a question: I'm currently reading a few things about orientability and understood this concept as the answer to the question: Given a surface and a unit normal vector field on it: Is there a consistent way to define an orientation by the right-hand rule.

Now I found the following definition: A set $S$ that is a compact subset of a $C^2$ submanifold $\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is an orientable $C^k$-surface with boundary $\partial S$, if we find an atlas $(\phi_a,U_a(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2,V_a)$ such that for every $C^k$ chart we have that

(i) $V_a \subset S$ or 
(ii) $V_a \cap S = \phi_a(D \cap \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2; y_1 \ge 0\})$, where $D$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I do not see how this answers the question of whether a consistent orientation is possible?
What is the relationship between these two properties and the orientability of a surface?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you already have a unit normal vector field on your surface, then you already have an orientation given "by the right-hand rule". The question of orientability would more likely be "Is it possible to put a well-defined unit normal vector field on my surface?". Think of a Moebius strip $M$ where no matter which side you choose to set your unit normal vector $v_p$ at a point $p$, extending this to a vector field in a continuous way along a circle going all the way around, you end up with $-v_p$ at $p$. So you can't have a unit normal vector field on $M$.

It seems to me that the definition you give with the atlas there is just that of a $C^k$ surface with boundary. To define an orientation via an atlas, you would require that the transition functions $\phi_{b}^{-1} \circ \phi_{a}$ all have positive Jacobians. This way, you can transport the canonical (ordered) basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on every tangent plane $T_pS$ via your maps $\phi_a$. Now the reason you require the Jacobians of the transition functions to be positive is to be sure that for $p \in V_a \cap V_b$, this process defines the same ordered basis on $T_pM$  whether you use $\phi_a$ or $\phi_b$. To get a unit normal vector field from this construction, just take for example the cross product of the oriented basis on each tangent plane and normalize. The fact that the order of the basis you chose on each tangent plane is locally the same assures you that you don't run into a problem like for the Moebius strip.

Comment: you are right in part (b) of the definition is the jacobian thing listed, but since you seem to know what my first two properties are about. could you please also give me a short hint, what they mean?

Comment: I think it just means that a chart $V_a \subset S$ is either (i) in the interior of your surface (so it's like an open disc, without boundary) or (ii) it contains a bit of the boundary of $S$. In this second case, you think of $V_a$ as a disc "going over the boundary" so that the portion of it that's on $S$ is just half of that disc, with its boundary being the bit of boundary of $S$ contained in $V_a$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If the surface has a well defined unit normal then it inherits the orientation of R3. At any point on the surface, let the set of preferred bases of its tangent plane be all of the bases which yield a preferred basis of R3 when the unit normal is taken as the first vector in the list.

Equivalently, contract the orientation 3 form of R3 by the unit normal to get an orientation 2 form for the surface.